# byte type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable

Tags: c#, byte, filestream, idisposable

Why I am getting error when using following code? Shouldn't using "using" keyword suffice? How can I fix it.

> Error: byte[] type used in a using statement must be implicitly
>   convertible to System.IDisposable

```
class Class1
{
     public void UploadFile()
     {
          using(var v = class2.GetByteStream())  //getting error on this line
          {
               //rest of code here
          }
     }
}

class Class2
{
     public byte[] GetByteStream()
     {
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
               //some code here
               return ms.ToArray();
          }
     }     
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The using statement is used to call the IDisposable.Dispose method and can only be used with types that implement IDisposable. The byte array does not need to be disposed and doesn't implement IDisposable.

Here is the correct code:

```
class Class1
{
     public void UploadFile()
     {
          var v = class2.GetByteStream();

          //rest of code here
     }
}

class Class2
{
     public byte[] GetByteStream()
     {
          using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
          {
               //some code here
               return ms.ToArray();
          }
     }     
}
```

Comment: Your code fixed the problem. But how do I know that objects are being closed and not getting leaked? Because this UploadFile() method is running in a loop and uploads 3000 files, and I can see in Task Manager that the memory being used by my application keep getting higher and higher as the program upload files. Or is this normal behavior?

Comment: In the code sample you have shown everything looks ok. Maybe something is not being disposed somewhere else in your application

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to tell you, you can't do that.

The `using` statement only exists to call `Dispose()`.

If your type doesn't have any native resources, it won't implement `IDisposable`, and won't need a `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the `using` block around the `MemoryStream` in `Class2.GetByteStream()`.

In `Class1.UploadFile()`, all you need is `byte[] v = class2.GetByteStream()`. The stream is already disposed of correctly in `GetByteStream()`.